# How to read Arabic text from text file?

Tags: c#, unicode, text-files

I have text file which contains Arabic words. And i using `StreamReader` to read the text file and and `StreamReader` not getting those words and return ??????.
I tried Binary reader to but it's not reading that. I am using windows application. Please let me know any ways.

Comment: Sorry not getting it.

Comment: Nothing is working properly.

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying the encoding using this StreamReader constructor:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true);
```

For reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143457.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path,Encoding.Default,true);
string dataReader=sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
```

try and see it's right

Comment: Can you please explain why you think this is the solution? Without context, it's not as helpful as it could be. Thanks!

Comment: StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path,Encoding.Default,true);             of course u most to set your system Region non-Unicode language "Arabic"

Comment: if u save your Arabic file as ASCII u lost your file                       open new file as note write ِArabic and save as... and "set Encoding UTF-8"          if u save it as "ASCII" you lost it and u can't recovery it ....